# Bind ng-options selected value with object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind a property of object with selected value. I have the following object.

```
  $scope.data = {    
   sectionQs: $scope.questions, 
   selectedQuestion: ''
  }
```

I want to set the selected value based on returned value from a function, that value will be one of the drop down sectionQs values. Like

```
$scope.data.selectedQuestion = returnedValue;
```

Here returnedValue is an object and value to be bind is structured as returnedValue.data.string. Trying to bind like this in UI.

```
 <select ng-model="data.selectedQuestion" ng-options="question.data.string for question in data.sectionQs"></select>
```

Here the selected value remains empty even after setting it. selectedQuestion property fills up when I see in debugger, but it doesn't show up in UI.

Comment: It looks like the options are being created by `ng-options` sets value as object of question and seems In `$scope.data.selectedQuestion` you are not passing object. Can you please what you get in $scope.data.sectionQs and in `$scope.data.selectedQuestion` ?

Comment: in sectionQs, I have array of question objects. and in selectedQuestion I have one array object. And one array object is structure as object.data.string.

Comment: can you create some fiddle or plunker for this